# Spring Boot Redirect to /

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to redirect the user to "/" page.

In my controller, I have:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView addUser (@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap model) {
    ...
    if (...) { 
            model.addAttribute("uploadFileError", true);
            return new ModelAndView("/", model);
    } 
    return new ModelAndView("/", model);
```

and in my receiving page:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String root(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    return "index";
    }
```

but Spring returns "Error resolving template [/], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use `return "redirect:"` `+ ` `YOU_URL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the explanation given it seems like you need to redirect to some other controller in the same server. Below code will suits you to manage this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView addUser(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap model) {

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/", model);
    }
```

For further reading you can refer to below differences of redirect and forward

**Forward:**

1. The request will be further processed on the server side
2. The client isn’t impacted by forward, URL in a browser stays the
   same
3. Request and response objects will remain the same object after
       forwarding.
4. Request-scope objects will be still available

**Redirect:**

1. The request is redirected to a different resource
2. The client will see the URL change after the redirect
3. A new request is created
4. Redirect is normally used within Post/Redirect/Get web development
   pattern

If you just want to test the redirection run below without MultipartFile @AlanBE

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView addUser(/* @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, */ HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap model) {

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public void addUser (@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response
            ModelMap model) {
    ...
response.sendRedirect("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView addUser (@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap model) {
    ...

    return "redirect:/ http://yoururl/";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you want to forward or redirect. 
Redirection is for external domains or servers while forwarding is within the same server to another resource for further processing.

There are 2 options for redirect:

```
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
```

Here, redirectedUrl is relative to the server context. In your case it seems to be "/".

But it can be a full/complete HTTP URL such as : http://localhost:8080/newDomain/s...

If forward is what you really intend, try:

```
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
```

Comment: I just need to redirect to '/'. How should I do it?

Comment: Try "redirect:/".

Comment: try the above code which has added.The test worked fine for redirection. @AlanBE

Comment: But are you redirecting to another domain ?  Forward was not wanted ?

Comment: Please do upvote of solution works

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to redirect here is simple to try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addUser (@RequestParam(value="file")MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request,
        ModelMap model) {
       ...
return new ModelAndView( "redirect:/index",model);

}
```

and receiving page like

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String root(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
...
return "index";
}
```